# Angular Observable Unsubscribe where?

Tags: angular, observable

I have a doubt on where I should unsubscribe from an Observable.

I have following function in a component:

```
  loadProjectDetails(projectId: number): void {

console.log('>> loadProjectDetails(), id=', projectId);

const subscription = this.projectService.getProjectById(projectId).subscribe(
  data => {

    this.component = ProjectComponent;
    this.injector = Injector.create([{provide: Project, useValue: data}], this.inj);
    this.localStorageService.setLastSelection(projectId, null, null);
    subscription.unsubscribe();

  }, error => {

    if (error.status === 400) {
      alert("There is no project with id=" + projectId);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
    subscription.unsubscribe();

  }
);
}
```

Does it make any sense to unsubscribe in the presented way or it is enough to unsubscribe in **ngOnDestroy()** method?

The **loadProjectDetails(projectId: number)** method fires up every time user hits a button, so it runs multiple times before the component will be destroyed.

Comment: Unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy()

Comment: Based upon your example. You only seem interested in the *first* emitted value, and therefore can use the `first()` operator. Which doesn't require you to unsubscribe.

Comment: @cgTag i've tried to use `first()` operator, but i didn't work for me. I tried it in this way: `this.projectService.getProjectById(projectId).pipe(first()).subscribe` To be specific - i didn't get any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't manually unsubscribe, 90% of the time. In this specific case, you're using a service to fetch data. If this service uses an http call, and thus the HttpClient, the observable is already closed once the call is finished and closed observables are already unsubscribed. If this is not the case, you'd only need the first element, and `first` or `take(1)` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unsubscribing in the ngOnDestroy would be more than enough for the majority of the components. However, if you only need your observable for something specific and you would use it just once in a component with a long life, you can use the solution you have to save resources, but for just one observable there isn't a high impact